# How to encrypt a image before upload to server side using angular 8?

Tags: angular, encryption, cryptojs

**This is my frontend of file upload component**
[image]

**This is the ts file to the above component**
[image]

what i need to know is that how to encrypt the image before upload to server side?If somone can provide a code that would be really helpfull...

Comment: All transmission between the client and the server will be encrypted if you're using a valid SSL setup - which obviously you will be in production - so you don't need to do anything

Comment: Thankyou for the answer @LukeJoshuaPark But my client want me to encrypt the image on client side. I tried to use CryptoJs library but i couldn't find where to use it.

Comment: Perhaps we are misunderstanding each other - should the image just be encrypted during transmission to the server - or should the image be encrypted and stored encrypted on the server too?  Should the server be capable of decrypting the image?

Comment: Image should be encrypted before transmission.That is on the Client side.Encrypted image will be store on the server.When retrieving  the image , it should be decrypt on the client side.I hope you understand my issue

Comment: U still dint get any answer to this ? Using CryptoJS i was able to do common string encryption. But dont know how to encrypt audio or image byte or buffer